# Getting cross, cross-compiling Rust crate that depends on libc, for Raspberry Pi

Tags: gcc, rust, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling my project from my M1 Mac for the Raspberry Pi. The project comprises circa 17Kloc and building it on the Pi exhausts available memory (and 1G of extra swap). Building it via cross compiler gets me this compiler complaint

```
error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils-gcc` installed?
```

.. which is reasonable, because while the foreign linker package `arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils` includes `arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils-ld` and `arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils-ranlib` as well as other familiar names, it lacks the C compiler.

But where *can* I get it? Not on Homebrew AFAIKS. This is a simplified reproduction of the problem.

`$HOME/.cargo/config` is

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld"
```

`Cargo.toml` is

```
[package]
name = "nics"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
network-interface = "0.1.3"
```

.. and `main.rs` is

```
use network_interface::{NetworkInterface, NetworkInterfaceConfig};

fn main() {
    let nics = NetworkInterface::show().unwrap();

    println!("Found {} NICs", nics.len());

    for itf in nics.iter() {
        println!("{:?}", itf);
    }
}
```

Following [this otherwise splendid article](https://amritrathie.vercel.app/posts/2020/03/06/cross-compiling-rust-from-macos-to-raspberry-pi/), I

1. installed the Rust target for the Raspberry Pi `rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf`
2. installed the linker `brew install arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils`
3. attempted to build it for the Pi with `cargo build --target armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf`

This fails saying ...

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `network-interface v0.1.3`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/martincowie/Development/rust/nics/target/debug/build/network-interface-77fc30e746fc938b/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  TARGET = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  CC_armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf = None
  CC_armv7_unknown_linux_musleabihf = None
  TARGET_CC = None
  CC = None
  CROSS_COMPILE = None
  CFLAGS_armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf = None
  CFLAGS_armv7_unknown_linux_musleabihf = None
  TARGET_CFLAGS = None
  CFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
  running: "arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-march=armv7-a" "-mfpu=vfpv3-d16" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-o" "/Users/martincowie/Development/rust/nics/target/armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf/debug/build/network-interface-339c444064457e48/out/src/target/macos/ffi/lladdr.o" "-c" "src/target/macos/ffi/lladdr.c"

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc` installed?
```

Where can I get `arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc`, or what more fundamental issue am I not seeing?

Comment: Might be relevant: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/cross-compiling-from-macos-to-arm/56060, and linked in there is https://github.com/MarioSchwalbe/homebrew-gcc-musl-cross

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [musl cross compiler toolchains](https://github.com/MarioSchwalbe/homebrew-gcc-musl-cross) might help you:

```
$ brew tap MarioSchwalbe/gcc-musl-cross
$ brew install gcc-8-musl-cross
```

(Disclaimer: Can't verify, don't own a Mac)